# EGit 2.3 new --no-ff option, how to use it?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit, git-merge

In EGit 2.3 they've added the no fast-forward merge ability according to their release documents

> "Support git merge --no-ff as an EGit preference."
>
> http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.3

Question I have is, where do you set this preference?  I tried Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration -> Repository Settings and then under [Core] setting mergeoptions = --no-ff but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following options for merge are recognized, which are used for all branches:

```
[merge]
    ff = true|false|only
```

When you only want to configure it for a certain branch, use the following:

```
[branch "name"]
    mergeoptions = --ff|--no-ff|--ff-only
```

I also extended the description in [New and Noteworthy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.3).